# related rates problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Sand is falling into a conical pile at the rate of $200$ cubic inches per minute.The radius of the circular base of the pile is increasing at $0.2$ inches per minute. Find the rate of change of the height of the pile when its height is $20$ inches and the diameter of the base is $30$ inches.

The answer in the book is:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{\pi}{3} 2r h \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{\pi}{3} r^2 \frac{dh}{dt} $$

my question is why he added $ \dfrac{\pi}{3} r^2 \dfrac{dh}{dt} $ to the equation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the product rule, combined with the chain rule.  What you have is the derivative of the volume function
$$
V=\frac{\pi}{3}r^2h.
$$

EDIT: You have two functions that are varying with respect to time, $\frac{\pi}{3}r^2$ and $h$.  The deriviative of the first:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\pi}{3}r^2=\frac{\pi}{3}(2r)\frac{dr}{dt}
$$
and the second:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}h=\frac{dh}{dt}.
$$
Now apply the product rule.

Comment: can you explain to me how to get the derivative of this function because i'm confused. I mean do i start with product rule for $ \frac{\pi}{3} \; and \;  r^2 \;  or \; i \; start \; with  \;r^2  \; and \; h $